# pgfutter importing blank lines

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone know why pgfutter is importing blank lines between records and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: are you in windows ? maybe your are facing this issue: https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter/issues/55
try to convert your csv to unix file (only CR as end of line)

Comment: Perhaps it is correctly importing the file you are providing. Are your sure the INPUT does not contain empty lines.